# A book to learn programming concepts

Tags: recursion, concept

does anybody know of a book where i can learn "introduction to programming tools in computer science including: data abstraction, recursion, higher-order functions, I/O, and data structures such as lists and trees. This course prepares students for success in AP Computer Science." I have a little programming experience, but i feel learning these things may really lessen the learning curve and give me a better understanding of programming

Comment: even if the concepts are always valid, you should let us know what language you're going to develop, if you have little programming experience it will speed you up to learn the concepts in the right language

Comment: Everyone I've seen has been how to do this in language X. Why language X, when this, why this how, ommitted. Too obvious to mention?. Written by Polly the Parrot? Read as many books as you can, learn a few languages. One of the most instructive things isd

Comment: is the differences. that five minute rule is daft...

Comment: If you are familiar with the german language, I can recomment a great lecture script, which really focusses on the generic concepts behind programming languages: Look for "Konzepte der Programmierung" on http://www.alternative-softwaresystemtechnik.de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). On MITOpenCorseware has [20 hours of lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/) which is related to the book. It does not cover all of the book but it's magical to watch!

In one hour you learn a programming language and in the last two you learn compilation techniques and how to make a garbage collector. It's pretty awesome.

Answer (score 0):

you can check let uc C,is a good book. it is in C language. 
pdf is available at http://www.cluster2.hostgator.co.in/files/writeable/uploads/hostgator99706/file/letusc-yashwantkanetkar.pdf . this book doesn't include data structure.